# Как сделать так, чтобы консоль не закрывалась?

Tags: python, консоль

У каждого окна в Windows есть справа сверху 3 кнопки - Свернуть, Во весь экран/Развернуть и Закрыть. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы консоль Python по вызову функции, делала кнопку Закрыть недоступной. Как это сделать?

Comment: Может, лучше сделайте своё собственное окно вместо консоли?

Comment: @andreymal нет, консоль - "фишка" моей программы